# How to convert hex value to single precision floating point number and also in double precision floating point number according to the IEEE-754 format

Tags: java, ieee-754

Can someone please tell me how i can convert a Hex string to its corresponding single precision or double precision floating point number according to the IEEE-754 format in java?

For example :
"4682E989" 
and 
"A4703D4A0B0B7441"

BR
suppi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [`Double.longbitsToDouble`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longBitsToDouble%28long%29).

> Returns the double value corresponding to a given bit representation. The argument is considered to be a representation of a floating-point value according to the IEEE 754 floating-point "double format" bit layout.

You can get a `long`from the hex representation with <del>[`Long.parseLong`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)</del> `new BigInteger(s, 16).longValue()` (as Peter Lawrey points out). `Long.parseLong` won't do because it fails on numbers larger than 2^63-1.

Comment: +1: And `new BigInteger(string, 16).longValue()` to parse the unsigned hex number.

Comment: @Suppi There's the analogous [`intBitsToFloat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,6.0/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat(int)) for floats.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example with correct answer .

Hex value = 440B1831

Expected Binary = 1000100000010110001100000110001

Expected float= 556.378

```
  Long decimal  =new BigInteger("440B1831", 16).longValue();
   String binary1 = java.lang.Long.toBinaryString(decimal);
    System.out.println(binary1);
     int intBits = Integer.parseInt(binary1, 2);
    float myFloat = Float.intBitsToFloat(intBits);
   System.out.println( myFloat);
```